# About proving a matrix equality

Tags: matrices

Can anyone help?

If $A$ is an invertible $n \times n$ matrix and $X,Y$ are $n \times n$ matrices such that $X = AY$ and $X = (A\times A)Y$, does it follow that $X = Y$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $A\times A$?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Thanks for bringing your questions here, hope you find it helpful and contribute to the site yourself.

Comment: is this the same as asking if $AY=Y$?

Comment: @user1551 It's A squared, sorry to make you confused. I'm new here, thanks.

Comment: @user1783444 Hmm I guess so.

Comment: I don't think you should start a question with "Can anyone help?", people will think "help with what? you haven't even said it yet!".

Answer (score 3):

We have $X = AY = A^2 Y$, which implies $0 = A^2 Y - AY = (A-I) AY$.

Now since A is invertible, either $A=I$ or $Y=0$. In either case, $X=AY=Y$.

Comment: Did you use that $A-I$ is invertible if $A \neq I$?

Comment: You got that $(A-I)Y=0$, ie. $AY=Y$, but how do you deduce that $A=I$ or $Y=0$?

Comment: Well, thanks. But what if we have BX=AY and B^2 X = A^2 Y? Does it still follow the same?

Comment: Ah yeah. Yes it does. Thanks again xD

Answer (score 2):

$X=AY$

$\Rightarrow Y=A^{-1}X=A^{-1}A^2Y=AY=X$

Comment: (+1), but I would have preferred this from right to left :)

Comment: Yeah thanks :) Hmm but I don't know why I feel this method will not bring me to solve the more general statement :

If B^k X = A^k Y for k = 1,2,...,2n, then X=Y

Comment: Oh, with n natural number and A,B,X,Y are given before.

Answer (score 1):

We have $X=A^2Y=AY.$ Now, $$A^2Y=AY\Rightarrow AY=Y$$ Since $A$ is invertible. Again $AY=X$, hence $X=Y.$